# ctrl + click (go to definition) not working in VSCode with ESLint + Vite + React when using alias

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint, vite

I have a React project in which I'm using Vite and ESLint.
I'm sure the path to the folders below are correct (at least from a structural POV).

However, I'm unable to CTRL + click imports or F12 them.
It says "No definition found for X" and I have this error:

`Unable to resolve path to module 'Unable to resolve path to module '@components/ImportCSV'.eslintimport/no-unresolved`, although the  relative path for this component is `webportal/src/components/ImportCSV.jsx` and it's exported like so: `export default function ImportCSV`

Here's my `jsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@": ["./src"],
      "@components": ["./src/components"],
      "@enums": ["./src/enums"],
      "@hooks": ["./src/hooks"],
      "@pages": ["./src/pages"],
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.js",
    "**/*.jsx"
  ]
}
```

I have tried adding "jsx": "react" to `jsconfig.json`'s compilerOptions but it didn't solve the issue. I have also tried writing the paths in other ways but none worked.

Here's my `vite.config.js`:

```
import path from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import svgr from '@svgr/rollup';

const buildDate = Date.now();

const resolvePath = srcPath => path.resolve(__dirname, srcPath);

export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': resolvePath('./src/'),
      '@components': resolvePath('./src/components'),
      '@enums': resolvePath('./src/enums'),
      '@hooks': resolvePath('./src/hooks'),
      '@pages': resolvePath('./src/pages'),
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    svgr(),
    react(),
  ],
  server: {
    port: 8080,
  },
  publicDir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/public'),
  build: {
    outDir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        opp: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.html'),
      },
      output: {
        entryFileNames: `[name]_${buildDate}.js`,
        chunkFileNames: `[name]_${buildDate}.js`,
        assetFileNames: `[name]_${buildDate}.[ext]`,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Here's the `.eslintrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'airbnb',
    'plugin:import/recommended',
  ],
  env: {
    browser: true,
    commonjs: true,
    es6: true,
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
  },
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      alias: {
        map: [
          ['@', './src'],
          ['@components', './src/components'],
          ['@enums', './src/enums'],
          ['@hooks', './src/hooks'],
          ['@pages', './src/pages'],
        ],
        extensions: [
          '.ts',
          '.tsx',
          '.js',
          '.jsx',
          '.json',
          '.svg',
        ],
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Versions of packages I have installed in `package.json`:

```
   "eslint": "^8.46.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.13.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-no-only-tests": "3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.13",
    "vite": "^4.4.9",
```

I also have this on my `package.json`:

```
  "babel": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        "babel-plugin-import",
        {
          "libraryName": "@mui/material",
          "libraryDirectory": "",
          "camel2DashComponentName": false
        },
        "core"
      ],
      [
        "babel-plugin-import",
        {
          "libraryName": "@mui/icons-material",
          "libraryDirectory": "",
          "camel2DashComponentName": false
        },
        "icons"
      ]
    ],
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

All you just need to add '/*' at the end of the paths in the jsconfig.json,.

Something like this,.

As per your example:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src"],
      "@components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
      "@enums/*": ["./src/enums/*"],
      "@hooks/*": ["./src/hooks/*"],
      "@pages/*": ["./src/pages/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Also you can find the documentation of VSCode here,..
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying! Unfortunately, that did not work. It seems that ctrl + click takes me to "reference" (on the same file) instead of source definition. :/